# Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i'm trying to change the preg_match check from url checking to username checking which is min/max 2-16chrs, dash, space & hypen acceptable. i'm getting this error

> **Warning:** preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 14

```
if(empty($string) || preg_match("#^([\w- ]{2,16}*(?:.[\w- ]{2,16}*)+):?(d+)?/?#i", $string))
```

old code that looked for URL

```
if(empty($string) || preg_match("#^(http|https|ftp)://([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(d+)?/?#i", $string))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
[\w- ]{2,16}*
```

You can't use `{2,16}` and `*` together, you can only use one or the other.

If you were looking to match groups of 2 to 16 `[\w- ]`s, at least 0 times, wrap it in a subpattern and attach the `*` outside:

```
(?:[\w- ]{2,16})*
```

Answer (score 2):

What BoltClock says is correct. But there are other problems with your regex as well. First, to solve your immediate problem, here's a regex, which validates a username to be from 2 to 16 characters long consisting only of letters, digits, underscores, dashes/hyphens and spaces:

```php
if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9_\- ]{2,16}$/', $string)) {
    // Valid username.
}
```

Note that there is no need for the `'empty() ||'` clause because the regex matches only if there are at least 2 chars.

Second, regexes are very useful (and can even be *fun!*), but if you are going to use them, you need to sit down and learn the syntax, plain and simple (its not that hard). I would strongly recommend spending an hour or two studying the basics. There is an excellent online tutorial at: [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). The time you spend there will pay for itself many times over. Happy regexing!