# php pregmatch - Compilation failed

Tags: php, preg-match

was wondering if someone could help with this one. This is the first time I've seen this error.

> **Warning**:  preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation
>   failed: nothing to repeat at offset 9

which is inrelation to this part of my code:

```
( isset( $_POST[$post_key] ) && $misc[2] === true && ! preg_match( $misc[0], $_POST[$post_key] ) )
```

and my full (bit thats relevant) piece of code is below.

The data sent over is as follows:

```
ajax-request    true
author          1
epi             2
jbid            781711001327010590
message         dfdf
type            send-invite
```

Anyone know any reason for this or what causes the error?

```
case 'send-invite' :

    if( free_member_is_logged_in() ) {

        $post_array = array(
            'message' => array(
                '#^.*{3,500}$#is',
                '<p class="error_message">Please enter a message between 3 and 500 characters.</p>',
                true
            ),
            'epi' => array(
                '#^[0-9]+$#is',
                '<p class="error_message">An internal error has occured. If this problem persists please contact support</p>',
                true
            ),
            'author' => array(
                '#^[0-9]+$#is',
                '<p class="error_message">An internal error has occured. If this problem persists please contact support.</p>',
                true
            ),
            'jbid' => array(
                '#^[0-9]+$#is',
                '<p class="error_message">Please specify a job which you have published.</p>',
                true
            )
        );

        $continue = true;

        foreach( $post_array as $post_key => $misc ) {
            if( 
                    ( ! isset( $_POST[$post_key] ) && $misc[2] === true ) 
                || 
                    ( isset( $_POST[$post_key] ) && $misc[2] === true && ! preg_match( $misc[0], $_POST[$post_key] ) ) 
                || 
                    ( isset( $_POST[$post_key] ) && $misc[2] === false && $_POST[$post_key] != '' && ! preg_match( $misc[0], $_POST[$post_key] ) ) 
            ) {

                $continue = false;
                $error_message = $misc[1];

            }
            ${cleankey($post_key)} = res($_POST[$post_key]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as here I guess - you can't use *{} together:

[Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685238/warning-preg-match-function-preg-match-compilation-failed-nothing-to-repe)

```
$post_array = array(
        'message' => array(
            '#^.*{3,500}$#is',
```

Answer (score 1):

> a message between 3 and 500 characters

The regex `#^.{3,500}$#is` would just be ok.

Comment: thanks for the help, sorry didn't refresh the page so the answer below lead me to your conclusion. Cheers anyway